# The zone 'projects/xxxx/zones/us-west3-a' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, gcloud-compute

I have a suspended instance that I want to bring up, but cannot because of the error in the title. I'd expect that there'd be an obvious way to choose a different zone in which to resume the instance, but I see nothing. As long as us-west3-a is overbooked, how can I resume execution of this instance elsewhere?

I'm not running a major service - this one instance is the entire operation, and given what I'm running (an ancient game server) load balancing or multi-region availability is out of the question. I just need to be able to run this instance *somewhere* when the need strikes.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to resume your instance in another zone you will need to create a snapshot first then create a new instance using the snapshot you have created. There are no possible ways to directly transfer an instance to another zone.  Below are the step by step procedure to do so:

How to  create snapshot

1. Go to the Compute Engine page > then select Snapshot.
2. Click Create Snapshot.
3. Select the disk of your instance.
4. Please check all your settings
5. Once you're done, please click the "Create" button.

How to create instance from a snapshot with new zone

1. Go to Compute Engine > Snapshots
2. Select the snapshot you need
3. Click Create Instance
4. Provide a name for your new instance
5. Select the new Region or Zone
6. Select other options needed ie. Machine type or GPU
7. Edit other settings like network and disk if needed
8. Click Create

Once the instance is created and started, it will be in the same state at the time you created the snapshot.

For more information and troubleshooting about the Stockout error, you can check the [GCP official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-instances#vm-not-created).

Comment: That's.... a lot of manual BS to have to go through just because my host datacenter is swamped. Are any of the SF/LA area datacenters going to give me better reliability when it comes to bringing this thing up when the need arises, or am I doomed to be playing this game forever? (If the answer is the latter, I'm just going to switch this over to AWS. I'm more familiar w/ that platform anyway, since I have my team on it at work. I just wanted to see if GCS was worth a look-see.)

Comment: Definitely, other regions have more reliability since it has less users in it and Google continuously increases their data center capacity. Another thing that you need to consider is the account type. Normally a free trial account has less opportunity than a paid one just like any other product. They also offer a feature called reservations that guarantees Google Cloud capacity, see this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reserving-zonal-resources) for details on how to use this feature. But it is still better to contact their support to find more possible options.